SpringBoot Security Auth - Clients and Machines
I am currently developing an application using Spring Boot and React. I am using Spring Security with OAuth2. When users visit my React application and request data from my Spring Boot backend, they are prompted to log in. They have the option to log in via GitHub or Google. This setup uses JSESSIONIDs, following the standard documentation.
Now, I need to allow another application to interact with my API, either by fetching data or sending data via POST requests. For example, I want to enable a simple JavaScript application running with Node.js to access my API.
I'm having trouble figuring out how to achieve this. Does someone know how to set up authentication and authorization for this scenario?
Thank you very much for your help! :)
Here is my securityFilterChain
@Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests( auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login( oauth2 -> oauth2.successHandler(oAuth2LoginSuccessHandler))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .build();
    }

and here my custom LoginSuccessHandler (Note that this is WIP)
@Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        OAuth2AuthenticationToken token = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;

        if("github".equals(token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId())){
            DefaultOAuth2User principal = (DefaultOAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();
            Map<String, Object> attributes = principal.getAttributes();
            String email = attributes.getOrDefault("email", "").toString();
            String name = attributes.getOrDefault("name", "").toString();
            userService.findByEmail(email)
                    .ifPresentOrElse(user -> {
                        DefaultOAuth2User newUser = new DefaultOAuth2User(List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name()))
                                , attributes, "id");
                        Authentication securityAuth = new OAuth2AuthenticationToken(newUser, List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name()))
                                , token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId());
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(securityAuth);
                    }, () -> {
                        BMUser userEntity = new BMUser();
                        userEntity.setRole(BMUserRole.ROLE_USER);
                        userEntity.setEmail(email);
                        userEntity.setName(name);
                        userService.createNewUser(userEntity);
                        DefaultOAuth2User newUser = new DefaultOAuth2User(List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userEntity.getRole().name()))
                                , attributes, "id");
                        Authentication securityAuth = new OAuth2AuthenticationToken(newUser, List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userEntity.getRole().name()))
                                , token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId());
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(securityAuth);
                    });
        }

        this.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true);
        this.setDefaultTargetUrl(frontendUrl);
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }

I've reviewed the official Spring Boot documentation, watched YouTube videos, and read Baeldung guides, but I've only been able to authenticate React users so far.

Preamble
It is nonsense to configure oauth2Login and oauth2ResourceServer in the same filter-chain. I know that many tutorials do like that, but that's mostly because authors copy from each other, not understanding what they are doing. You won't find any sample like that in Spring's official doc and there are reasons why they provide with different Boot starters for the 2. To name a few:

authorization code flow (oauth2Login) concerns clients (like any other OAuth2 flow) but not resource servers. Clients are responsible for acquiring tokens and authorizing their requests to resource servers with it. Resource servers are accountable for validating access tokens authorizing requests they receive.
clients with oauth2Login are stateful (need sessions to drive the flow and store tokens), resource servers can (and should) be stateless. As a consequence, clients need protection against CSRF and resource servers don't.
clients with oauth2Login are usually expected to redirect unauthorized requests to login, when all that resource servers can do is returning a 401
(again, how to get an access token is none of their business).

How to authenticate a Javascript-based frontend with OAuth2
According to the latest recommendations, this should be done on a confidential OAuth2 client running on the server.
But as REST APIs are much better configured as (stateless) resource servers, this means using a Backend For Frontend between the SPA and the REST API. I wrote an article for that on Baeldung. An alternative provided that the REST API is a monolith, is to configure it as a (stateful) client with oauth2Login (but of course, that will poorly scale and you'll be keeping in session access tokens that will never be used).
In your case, I'd follow the tutorial I linked above, configuring Github and Google as identity providers in Keycloak.
